# Reading facebook direct messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to read direct messages using the facebook graph api? I can see a reference to a message object in the docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) but can’t see a call to get a collection of messages for a facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found this in the **notifications** call in the graph api ...

https://graph.facebook.com/id/notifications

I needed **manage_notifications** and **read_mailbox** extended permissions for this to work as well

Answer (score 0):

using graph api and fql you can read messages 
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/  thread and message

be aware there is any difference for FB backend if a message has been sent from during online chat or while offline from chat